# Reading from a file using scanner? What is wrong with this code?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My code keeps giving me this error message when I try to run it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at readingFile.readFile(readingFile.java:18)
    at apples.main(apples.java:6)
```

What do you think is the problem? I am watching buckys tutorials while doing this. It worked for him but not me.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class readingFile {
    private Scanner x;

    public void openFile() {
        try {
            x = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Ike\\Desktop\\chinese.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("could not find file");
        }
    }

    public void readFile() {
        while(x.hasNext()) {
            String a = x.next();
            String b = x.next();
            String c = x.next();

            System.out.printf("%s %s %\n", a,b,c);
        }
    }

    public void closeFile() {
        x.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: before you call next(), you should check hasNext()

Comment: Is `String c = x.next();` located in line 18?

Comment: @Smutje yes. it is located on line 18

Comment: @Petar what exactly do you mean by I should check hasNext()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With every `next()` call you are moving scanner pointer to next matched pattern. So you need to check `hasNext()` before every `next()` call.

Like this,

```
    while(x.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(x.next());
    }
    System.out.println();
```

> The next() and hasNext() methods and their primitive-type companion
>   methods (such as nextInt() and hasNextInt()) first skip any input that
>   matches the delimiter pattern, and then attempt to return the next
>   token. Both hasNext and next methods may block waiting for further
>   input. Whether a hasNext method blocks has no connection to whether or
>   not its associated next method will block.[[Java doc reference]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)